# Find a string in a text file and add text at the beginning to that line in php

Tags: php

I have a text file:

John customerA 
Michael customerB 
Joe CustomerA
Jacky CustomerC

How to add 'active' string into the beginning of the text and only for 'customerA', so the output will be

active John customerA 
Michael customerB 
active Joe CustomerA 
Jacky CustomerC

Thanks

Comment: Not to discourage your question, but it really sounds like you should use a database...

Comment: a database would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips..

1. Use fopen to read store the file in an array line by line  (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
2. Run a foreach loop for that array and check for occurrence of 'A' at the end of string. (useful function: strlen, strpos)
3. If 'A' is found add 'active ' at the beginning of that string. ($x = 'active '.$x;)
4. Use fputs and and fclose to update the file.(http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php)

If you have any technical problem in any of the steps SO is open :)

Answer (score 0):

Text Files are not databases and you can't just go to a particular line and change things in it.  What you can do is open the file, change it in memory and over-write the file with your changed version.

Like the other commentors, I suspect that you'll be asking about concurrency issues that are solved by databases.

Assuming there was a magic function like say, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php that creates an array of lines from a text file, I would hope you could then foreach through that array and  do a basic string search and string concatenation, followed by fopen/fwrite of the lines back to the file using a combination of fopen and fwrite.

Anything further and I'd essentially be writing the program for you, but you may find this much easier using a database, even if that is a local database like http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php